# Query Where in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

i want to make query SQL like this in Django

```
select auth_group.name auth_user.username 
from  auth_group, auth_user, auth_user_groups
where auth_user.id = auth_user_groups.id AND auth_group.id = auth_group.id AND auth_group.name = "Operator";
```

table:

```
auth_user -> id, username

auth_group -> id, name

auth_user_groups -> id, user_id, group_id
```

and i try query in django like this

```
p = User.objects.all().prefetch_related('groups').get(groups='Operator')
```

but error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Operator'`

can you help me solve this problem?`

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
get(groups='Operator')
```

To

```
get(groups__name='Operator')
```

You could get several results so you probably should do:

```
filter(groups__name='Operator')
```